# Trying to get college SAT scores from http://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/, unable to form query?

Tags: data.gov

I need to get SAT related data for colleges but using the SAT related parameters I am not getting the data back. It is giving me an error i.e. invalid field, is this data not exposed under Schools endpoint?
Here is [my query](https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools.json?school.degrees_awarded.predominant=2,3&_fields=id,school.name,2013.student.size,school.sat_scores.25th_percentile.critical_reading&api_key=2e%5Bskip%5Dck).

Answer (score 1):

I think that for anything but the root fields (ID and location), you need to specify a year. Also, SAT scores fall under the admissions category rather than the schools category. So if you change your query to something like this it should work:

https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools.json?school.degrees_awarded.predominant=2,3&_fields=id,school.name,2013.student.size,2013.admissions.sat_scores.25th_percentile.critical_reading&api_key=2e[skip]ck

I changed "school.sat_scores.25th_percentile" to  "2013.admissions.sat_scores.25th_percentile.critical_reading".

The data dictionary on this page is pretty helpful for this stuff: https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/documentation/